# Running NUnit Tests in .NET Core with ReSharper

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

Is it possible to run NUnit tests with R#, when these tests are in a .NET Core project?
I have been unable to do that. If I select the option to produce outputs, then R# cannot find the NUnit assembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**: The NUnit team and I have released full .NET Core support, it is a console runner that runs tests at the command line and runs tests within Visual Studio's Test Explorer. See [NUnit 3 Tests for .NET Core RC2 and ASP.NET Core RC2](http://www.alteridem.net/2016/06/18/nunit-3-testing-net-core-rc2/) for more info.

---

Neither R#, nor the NUnit Visual Studio adapter, or even the nunit3-console.exe support .NET Core yet. [.NET Core projects currently must be tested using NUnitLite](http://www.alteridem.net/2015/11/04/testing-net-core-using-nunit-3/) by creating a self-executing test assembly.

The NUnit team is working on a better solution that will hopefully be released in the next few months.

Answer (score 6):

> **Update December 2016:**  ReSharper 2016.3 is now available. The xUnit and NUnit test runners will work on ReSharper >= 2016.3

ReSharper Early Access Program 2016.3 EAP now supports running .NET Core Tests from R# and it's Awesome it even runs the tests for each framework.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+2016.3+EAP

[image]

Project.json (change as appropriate for your use case)

```
  {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "testRunner": "nunit",

  "runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": {},
    "win8-x64": {},
    "win10-x64": {}
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "NUnit": "3.4.1",
    "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-2"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
    },

    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Update - It's worth noting that this is regarding netcore RC2 tooling(project.json). Development for rc4 csproj and visual studio 2017 test runner still appears to be underway and will be in the next release. [2016.3 release notes](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/#v2016-3-visual-studio-2017-rc-initial-support)

Comment: Still does not support in 2017.1: ReSharper currently doesn’t support continuous testing for .NET Core unit tests. This will be fixed in the next updates. https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/04/03/meet-resharper-ultimate-2017-1/#UnitTesting

Answer (score 3):

In vs 2015.3 with Resharper 2017.2, you can create unit test using NUnit for .Net Core 2.

- Create .Net Core 2 library
- Modify .csproj, add nuget libraies:

  ```
      <ItemGroup>
          <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0" />
          <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.8.1" />
          <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.8.0" />
        </ItemGroup>
  ```

For more details read : [Nunit docs: .NET Core and .NET Standard](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard)