# ReSharper 2018.1.2 NUnit TestCaseSource (.NET Core / VS2017)

Tags: .net-core, nunit, resharper

I have seen all of the following questions:

- [NUnit .NET Core running through Resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445769/nunit-net-core-running-through-resharper)
- [Running NUnit Tests in .NET Core with ReSharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575110/running-nunit-tests-in-net-core-with-resharper)
- [NUnit TestCaseSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722888/nunit-testcasesource)

Despite following all of their advice and having the following lines in all of my 
test projects:

```
<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.10.1" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.7.2" />
```

I am still getting the following errors in the Unit Test Explorer window of ReSharper (version 2018.1.2):

```
2018.06.23 11:22:21.292   ERROR Transition failed: Transition from state <HandShake> on event <remote::.ProtocolVersion>. Cause: System.InvalidOperationException: Test-cases are missing for the selected tests. Rebuild the project and try again. at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.DotNetCore.DotNetVsTest.DotNetVsTestExecution.SendGetProcessStartInfo() at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.ActionHolders.ArgumentLessActionHolder.Execute(Object argument) at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.ExecuteEntryAction(IActionHolder actionHolder, ITransitionContext`2 context)

--- EXCEPTION #1/1 [LoggerException]
Message = “
  Transition failed: Transition from state <HandShake> on event <remote::.ProtocolVersion>.
  Cause: System.InvalidOperationException: Test-cases are missing for the selected tests. Rebuild the project and try again.
     at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.DotNetCore.DotNetVsTest.DotNetVsTestExecution.SendGetProcessStartInfo()
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.ActionHolders.ArgumentLessActionHolder.Execute(Object argument)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.ExecuteEntryAction(IActionHolder actionHolder, ITransitionContext`2 context)
”
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = “
  at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.DotNetCore.DotNetVsTest.DotNetVsTestProtocol.<.ctor>b__22_14(Object sender, TransitionExceptionEventArgs`2 args)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.StateMachine`2.RaiseEvent[T](EventHandler`1 eventHandler, T arguments, ITransitionContext`2 context, Boolean raiseEventOnException)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.StateMachine`2.OnExceptionThrown(ITransitionContext`2 context, Exception exception)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.Contexts.TransitionContext`2.OnExceptionThrown(Exception exception)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.HandleException(Exception exception, ITransitionContext`2 context)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.HandleEntryActionException(ITransitionContext`2 context, Exception exception)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.ExecuteEntryAction(IActionHolder actionHolder, ITransitionContext`2 context)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.ExecuteEntryActions(ITransitionContext`2 context)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.Entry(ITransitionContext`2 context)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.EnterShallow(ITransitionContext`2 context)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.EnterHistoryNone(ITransitionContext`2 context)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.EnterByHistory(ITransitionContext`2 context)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.Transitions.Transition`2.Fire(ITransitionContext`2 context)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.Fire(ITransitionContext`2 context)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.StateMachine`2.Fire(TEvent eventId, Object eventArgument)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.ActiveStateMachine`2.ProcessEventQueue(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Appccelerate.StateMachine.ActiveStateMachine`2.<Start>b__32_0()
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(Object obj)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.LongRunningThreadWork(Object obj)
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(Object obj)
”

2018.06.23 11:22:21.315   ERROR System.InvalidOperationException: Test-cases are missing for the selected tests. Rebuild the project and try again.
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.DotNetCore.DotNetVsTest.DotNetVsTestExecution.SendGetProcessStartInfo()
   at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.ActionHolders.ArgumentLessActionHolder.Execute(Object argument)
   at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.ExecuteEntryAction(IActionHolder actionHolder, ITransitionContext`2 context)
2018.06.23 11:22:21.316    WARN Element UnitTests.Tests.RegressionTests was left pending after its run completion.
2018.06.23 11:22:21.316    WARN Element UnitTests.Tests.RegressionTests.TestAllRegressions was left pending after its run completion.
```

These are the newest versions of each of these packages, but I have also tried matching NUnit's version to the TestAdapter's version (3.10.0). The most baffling part of this is that *Visual Studio's Test Explorer* has no problem running the tests! I would very much like to use ReSharper's explorer to easily run their profiling and coverage tools on my tests.

Moreover, at some point in time ReSharper's test explorer *used* to work, but I'm not aware of the particular version combination that led to it. This setup still works for basic `[Test]` style tests and only fails for `[TestCaseSource]` tests.

**ETA:** ReSharper is also not running namespace-level setup and tear-down fixtures. Maybe this is part of the problem?

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug. JetBrains fixed it in ReSharper 2018.2 EAP 5. It's still finicky, but when it works, it works.